# is there a simple notation for the subtraction of a member from a set?

Tags: calculus, elementary-set-theory, notation

sometimes we use notation $S;x$ as an abbreviation for $S\cup \lbrace x\rbrace$.

(H.B. Enderton, *Mathematical Introduction to Logic*.)

but we also sometimes need delete a member from a set.

for example, in $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of limit, we have to consider a domain $(x-\delta,x+\delta)-\lbrace a\rbrace$ to decide $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$.

so I think there might(should) be a simple notation for this kind of operation.

is there any notation for this kind of operation?

Comment: Depending on the set, I like to use a subscript "$\ne a$" to eliminate $a$, e.g. $\mathbb{R}_{\ne 0}$ is the nonzero reals. This notation is used in, for instance, Dummit & Foote's abstract algebra text, since the set of nonzero elements of a ring or field is sometimes relevant, and denoted $R_{\ne 0}$ or $F_{\ne 0}$ as a result. Of course, if the set is not represented with a single letter, this looks ugly

Comment: \setminus = [Set difference](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Set_Difference)

Comment: OP is clearly aware of setminus/set difference, based on their use of $(x-\delta,x+\delta) - \{a\}$. $S\setminus T$ and $S-T$ are equivalent notations for the same thing.

Comment: I thought at $S\cap \lbrace x\rbrace^\complement$

Comment: That's also really not better, if anything it's worse because it requires even more writing. OP is looking for a notation that's more concise than $S - \{x\}$, not just a definition or an equivalent set.

Comment: We have Set Exclusion : $S - \{x\}$ & $S \setminus \{x\}$. We have Set Inclusion : $S \cup \{x\}$. We have Element Inclusion : $S ; x$. We can invent some new notation to indicate Element Exclusion : $S ! x$.

Comment: Isn't it just $S \backslash \{ x \}$?

Comment: OP wants Element Exclusion **without** making the Set $\{x\}$ , @Porky , like the Element Inclusion notation. That will make "3" Characters to "1" Character !

Comment: Creating an ever more compact notation that no one uses or can follow is not a good idea. $S \backslash \{ x \}$ is so suggestive you can guess what it means without being told, which is ideal.

Comment: Ah, I see. Well, I've never seen $S;x$ until now and not sure it really helps!